# How Do You Make a Responsive Grid Using - Display :Grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Please Could Somebody show me the code to make this Grid Responsive. I have been trying to figure it out from a multitude of online blogs but I just can't do it. Do I have to use Media Queries?

Any system; anyway to make a responsive Grid using Display: Grid- would really be appreciated.

If you show me once I will adopt the method. Thanks

This is the grid I have made.

https://codepen.io/mrlondon/project/live/DvxJvL/

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("wallpaper2.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.topdiv {
  background: pink;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  background: pink;
  height: 2000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 350px 350px 350px 350px 350px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  Padding: 30px;
}

.wrapper img {
  border: 2px solid #f0c330;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #f0c330;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.lastlist {
  padding-right: 65px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f0c330;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
}


}
.h2one {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  color: #f0c330;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.box1listone {
  background: black;
  postion: relative;
  top: 30px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  Margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.box1listone li {
  display: block;
}
.box1listtwo {
  background: black;
  postion: relative;
  top: 30px;
  right: 75px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  Margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.box1listtwo li {
  display: block;
}
.h2two {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  color: #f0c330;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.h2three {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 32px;
  top: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.paragraph1 {
  margin: 25px;
  color: #f0c330;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <nav>
    <h1>Daniel Savva</h1>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#">  Home</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">  Gallery</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">  About</a> </li>
      <li class="lastlist"> <a href="#">  Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="topdiv">
  <h2 class="h2three"> A Spiritual Man </h2>

</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jySfU10IQu4">
      <img src="picture1.jpg" alt="Picture1">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hF-QqKiT1bI">
      <img src="picture2.jpg" alt="picture2">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_9tX4eHztY">
      <img src="picture3.jpg" alt="picture3">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdrCfNdDrH8">
      <img src="picture45.jpg" alt="picture45">
    </a>
  </div>





  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-9dxYcH7sg">
      <img src="picture55.jpg" alt="picture55">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu__TzWfpss">
      <img src="picture66.jpg" alt="picture66">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUvVdTlA23w">
      <img src="picture77.jpg" alt="picture77">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Soa3gO7tL-c">
      <img src="picture9.jpg" alt="picture9">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEgX64n3T7g">
      <img src="picture10.jpg" alt="picture10">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVL-zZnD3VU">
      <img src="picture11.jpg" alt="picture11">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S71_vIMQ0YY">
      <img src="picture12.jpg" alt="picture12">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FrOQC-zEog">
      <img src="picture13.jpg" alt="picture13">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Which part of the site should be displayed as a grid? Can you prune your posted code - which I've converted into a runnable snippet in order to try and help - (html and css) down to just the "*[mcve]*" code? We don't need everything, just the part that's relevant to your question..

Comment: The whole page distorts and displays incorrectly when I resize the browser. It is supposed to be a picture gallery, so I would primarily like to know, how to make the images respond properly when the browser is resized. <div class="gallery">

Comment: Okay, should the images all be the same size within the grid? What size should that be? And, please, [edit] your question to pare the code down to the minimum required.

Comment: I cannot make a minimal reproducible example because I want the whole page to be responsive. Starting with the Grid. You can see where the grid is because it says- display: Grid in the CSS

Comment: Yes thanks, all images should be same size

Comment: Image size I tried to do- minmax (240px, 1fr) but that didn't work for me. I would like the number of images per row to reduce as the browser narrows. All the way down to only one image if it is viewed on a smart phone.

Comment: Unfortunately, as it stands, it seems that you're asking us to write the CSS for your entire site; we're here to help with specific problems one a one-problem-per-question basis. If you have multiple problems/issues with different aspects of your site then I would ask you to narrow this question down to one specific problem and, as I asked earlier, that you focus your question, and the code, on that *one* problem. Solving this problem, whatever it might be, will hopefully help you learn how you might handle the rest of the site.

Comment: Yes I understand. So could you just show me how to make the number of pictures per row reduce as the browser narrows. Just that one thing. By adjusting the code I have written ?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some ways here

1. you can use the Grid System of [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) or other CSS Frameworks(recommended)
2. If you want to make your own grid system. my suggestion for you is the SCSS Mixin 
   ability to make a powerful one(that I had made it before). you can study this 
   [Article](https://benjaminhorn.io/code/simple-sass-mixins-for-generating-grids-similar-to-bootstrap/). Anyway, you can use the below code blocks.

   ```
        @mixin grid-generator($size, $grid-columns) {
            @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
                  .col-#{$size}-#{$i}-#{$grid-columns} {
                   width: percentage($i / $grid-columns);
                 float: left;
         }
       }
    }
   ```

   And use mixin again to make them responsive

   ```
                       @mixin respond-from($media) {
                           @if $media == xs {
                               @media (min-width: 0px)  { @content; }
                           } @else if $media == sm {
                             @media (min-width: 768px) { @content; }
                         } @else if $media == md {
                               @media (min-width: 1200) { @content; }
                          } @else if $media == lg {
                           @media (min-width: 1440) { @content; }
                         } @else if $media == xl {
                            @media (min-width: 1800) { @content; }
                           }
                       }


                       @include grid-generator(xs, 12);
                       @include respond-from(sm) {
                             @include grid-generator(sm, 12);
                       }
                       @include respond-from(md) {
                             @include grid-generator(md, 12);
                       }

                       @include respond-from(lg) {
                                @include grid-generator(lg, 12);
                       }

                       @include respond-from(xl) {
                                @include grid-generator(xl, 10);
                                @include grid-generator(xl, 12);
                      }
   ```